# Can a refugee holding a US Green Card travel to South Korea without a visa?

Tags: south-korea, refugees

I am a refugee from Cambodia with a Green Card in the US. I will get a refugee travel document, which is like a passport. Can I travel to South Korea? Will I need a visa? If so, how do I get it? Basically will Korea let me in with a travel document?

Comment: As in all cases where you wonder whether you need a visa or not: assume you do and ask a consulate or embassy.

Answer (score 1):

South Korea's policy on immigration is nationality based. Since you're Cambodian, you need a visa. The only way for you to visit Korea without a visa would be to travel in a triangle, taking advantage of the 30-day visa exemption for people who:

- transit through Korea, and
- have a visa from a few countries, including the US. Since you have a green card, that'd work.

But you would have to fly something like:

US - Korea, Korea - third country, and then third country - US.

You couldn't fly on a return ticket US-Korea without a visa.

Comment: I wonder, does it have to be a reasonable transit. For example could you get away with doing US - Korea - Canada - USA.

Comment: Or the reverse, like US Korea Taiwan US.

Answer (score 0):

According to IATA Timatic, used by airlines and travel agents to verify passengers travel document requirements, you would require a visa to enter the Republic of South Korea.

A search in [TravelDoc](https://www.traveldoc.aero/Passenger/Check) expresses it thus:

> Refugee Travel Document issued by United States of America to a national of Cambodia is not listed as an accepted document by Republic of Korea (South).

Comment: Saying that a refugee travel document is not listed as an accepted document isn't the same as saying that someone holding such a document needs a visa; it's saying that TIMATIC cannot confirm that the person would be admitted.

Comment: @phoog and thus that the airline should refuse boarding.